# Erlang : RPC to a node with output on that node

Tags: erlang

Is there  a way to make an rpc call to a node, but have the output displayed on that node, not just on the calling node ( in fact I would not be too bothered if the calling node did not display the output ).

While I understand that I can use

```
rpc:call( Node, erlang, display, [ someTerm ] ).
```

and that will display "someTerm" on Node, what I really want is to get the result of an executed method displayed on the remote node terminal, so that given the attempt to run ls on Node :

```
rpc:call( Node, c, ls, [] ).
```

it will actually write the results the folder contents to the terminal of Node.

The idea being that I can drive a presentation from a single node, but have the nodes I am driving display the history of actions on them.

Comment: rpc:call( Node, c, ls, [] ) is showing result on node() but not on Node. Do you mean you want see result on Node? Your last sentence say it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try ;-)

```
rpc:call( Node, c, ls, [] ).
```

or when you want display it on `Node`

```
spawn(Node, fun()->group_leader(whereis(user),self()), c:ls() end).
```

or much more funny example which redirect output of local process to another terminal of `Node`

```
group_leader(rpc:call(Node, erlang, whereis, [user]), self()),
c:ls(),
group_leader(whereis(user), self()).
```

Comment: apologies.. I expressed that very poorly - I have re-expressed

Comment: I have added example how redirect output to another node.