# Erlang: How to view output of io:format/2 calls in processes spawned on remote nodes

Tags: erlang, distributed, rpc, spawn

I am working on a decentralized Erlang application. I am currently working on a single PC and creating multiple nodes by initializing `erl` with the `-sname` flag.

When I spawn a process using `spawn/4` on its home node, I can see output generated by calls `io:format/2` within that process in its home `erl` instance.

When I spawn a process remotely by using `spawn/4` in combination with `register_name`, output of `io:format/2` is sometimes redirected back to the `erl` instance where the remote `spawn/4` call was made, and sometimes remains completely invisible.

Similarly, when I use `rpc:call/4`, output of `io:format/2` calls is redirected back to the `erl` instance where the `rpc:call/4' call is made.

How do you get a process to emit debugging output back to its parent `erl` instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can supply 1st argument to io:format/3 on the second node, using result of erlang:group_leader() from the first node.

Starting first node, registering local shell process group leader globally:

```
erl -sname a
(a@localhost)1> global:register_name(global_io_srv, group_leader()).
yes
```

Starting second node, connecting, using globally registered process as io device

```
erl -sname b
(b@localhost)1> net_kernel:connect(a@localhost).
true
(b@localhost)2> io:format(global:whereis_name(global_io_srv),"test output",[]).
ok
```

You will see test output in the first node.
This is the same way that Christian suggested, just a bit more explicit. So you can have error_logger for production logging and io:format/3 just for quick debugging.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out myself and see if it works. Might be a few days before I get around to revisiting this problem, though. I'm curious, is this common knowledge? I spent hours scouring Google and asking questions in #erlang and have not come across this solution yet.

Comment: No, it was gained through frustration-intensive process. Io subsystem was undocumented for a long time until recently. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is processes with their group leader set to a pid on the node they were spawned from. See [erlang:group_leader](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#group_leader-0). The group leader is where they send their output to.

You call this output "debugging output", so are you sure that you dont want to start the sasl application on the nodes and use [error_logger](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html)?

Answer (score 3):

See mine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872198/erlang-rpc-to-a-node-with-output-on-that-node/873242#873242) to question [Erlang : RPC to a node with output on that node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872198/erlang-rpc-to-a-node-with-output-on-that-node/) for some details how to achieve output to different places. Which is not mentioned, you can run remote shell even in running shell. Just press `Ctrl+G` (`^G` hint on startup) and than you have help under `h` (press `h` and than `Enter`).

Example: Assume you have running erlang node by `erl -sname foo`. Than:

```
$ erl -sname bar
Erlang R13B04 (erts-5.7.5) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
(bar@hynek-notebook)1>
User switch command
 --> r 'foo@hynek-notebook'
 --> j
   1  {shell,start,[init]}
   2* {'foo@hynek-notebook',shell,start,[]}
 --> h
  c [nn]            - connect to job
  i [nn]            - interrupt job
  k [nn]            - kill job
  j                 - list all jobs
  s [shell]         - start local shell
  r [node [shell]]  - start remote shell
  q        - quit erlang
  ? | h             - this message
 --> c
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
(foo@hynek-notebook)1>
```