# BEAM behaviour RPC call between 2 nodes

Tags: erlang, elixir, gen-server

I have 2 nodes,

let's call them A and B.

B has a GenServer module that, when started, monitor A. (This module only exists on B)
this GenServer is started by A when A connects to B.

If A dies when connected to B, B should kill itself using `:init.stop()`

Here's the code of the GenServer:

```
defmodule Monitor do
  use GenServer

  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], [])
  end

  def init([]) do
    {:ok, %{}, 0}
  end

  def handle_info(:timeout, s) do
    start(:"A@127.0.0.1")
    {:noreply, s}
  end
  def handle_info({:nodedown, node}, state) do
    s_node = node |> to_string
    case s_node do
      "A" <> _ ->
        IO.puts "A is down, killing myself !"
        :init.stop()
      _ ->
        :ko
    end
    {:noreply, state}
  end
  def handle_info(_, s) do
    {:noreply, s}
  end

  def start(node) do
    res = Node.monitor(node, true)
    IO.puts "Starting to monitor: #{inspect node}"
  end
end
```

I start both node, A and B. I connect A to B. I start the Monitor using this command in A :

```
> :rpc.call(:"B@127.0.0.1", Monitor, :start_link, [])
{:ok, #PID<8440.594.0>}
```

If I disconnect gracefully A from B with `Node.disconnect`, everything works as expected, B is detecting the node A down and is killing itself.

However, if I kill the console of A with `Ctrl-C Ctrl-C`, or even `Ctrl-g / q`
The GenServer on B with pid `<0.594.0>` doesn't exist anymore and therefore can't detect A being down.
Is the Pid "linked" to A for some reason ?

**PS**
I tried with `Node.spawn` and calling spawn in the :rpc.call, I get the same result

**PS 2**
If I start the GenServer from the B console, when killing A with either `Node.disconnect` or `Ctrl-C Ctrl-C`, it works as expected...

**PS 3**
I thought that it might come from the fact that I call :start_link, but I have the same behaviour with :start (without link)

**subsidiary question**
*Answered by `Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil` in the comments...*

Why all the IO.puts are printed on A while the GenServer is technically running on B ?

Comment: If you kill the console you kill the local Erlang VM and so it cannot and does not send anything further to the other VM.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff, yes but the Node.monitor on B, should be called since, the node A is down. cf: PS2

Comment: Who do you expect to call monitor on B?

Comment: @mudasobwa: Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question... I would like A to start Monitor on B when A connects to B... Monitor should not be launched is A is not connected to B. Is that the answer your were expecting ?

Comment: afterwards, I expect that Node.monitor, send the node down to the GenServer, when A is down

Comment: Treat `Node.disconnect` as `kill -HUP` (or `kill -TERM`) and `Ctrl`+`C` `Ctrl`+`C` as `kill -KILL`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I'm not sure what you mean ?

Comment: I mean [Unix Signals](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_01.html). Once the Erlang VM is killed, it does not send anything anywhere, nor shut the running applications properly.

Comment: I agree with you... but Monitor is running on node B (which still runs) and Node.monitor should detect that A has been disconnected, either properly or not. If the Monitor has been started through B's console, everything works fine, so why it does not when starting the GenServer with a RPC call from A's console ?

Comment: Add subsidiary question see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590481/49197 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/873242/49197

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil : Thanks for the subsidiary question...

Comment: why do you setup the monitoring in a timeout handler (which I think won't be called) instead of simply in init?

Comment: @cdegroot it is called because of the 0 in the init return. I did some test. At first I launched it in the init , but I though maybe the unit process was linked to the node so I tried this way to be sure it runs on the remote node. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `:rpc.call(:"B@127.0.0.1", Monitor, :start_link, [])` you link your `Monitor` process to the current shell (and also set `group_leader` to the `:user` process at `A` which basically prevents you from seeing output `IO.puts "A is down, killing myself !"` once A is down.) So it means when A dies the shell running at A die as well and your `Monitor` as well because linked.
So first of all, you should use `GenServer.start()` for starting by `:rpc.call()` or set process flag `:trap_exit` to true or put it in the supervisor tree of an app running at node B. The second, set `group_leader` to `user` process at node B.

P.S.: I'm not familiar with Elixir syntax so I do not provide code.

Comment: I'll try to set the group_leader, because using GenServer.start() did not change a thing, cf PS3 of my post

Comment: Changing the group_leader of the process to node B is the correct solution ! Thank you

Comment: @TheSquad: You should do both because the server will die unless you `trap_exit`.